# Adding new .cshtml view to Visual Studio solution

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view

I'm trying to add a new `WebPage.cshtml` view to my VS solution, but when I compile/run my solution (F5) on my localhost, the view is empty.  It's just a simple HTML page.  Why is it empty?

I'm new to MVC development and so I suspect that I am missing an important concept related to how Models, Controllers, and Views work together to produce the view, however, I've read about it enough that I understand the basic concept of each.

I've been playing around with the controller and am guessing that I need something like the following before the view will work:

```
    public ActionResult WebPage()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Is that correct?

What other pieces to the puzzle am I missing?

Comment: `WebPage.cshtml` needs to be located under a directory of the same name as your controller (just the name minus the suffix "controller") which should be in the *Views* folder *Views\ControllerName\WebPage.cshtml*.

Comment: It is basis. Spend one day and read this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1 It will be more useful than any short answer.

Comment: @asymptoticFault Already done.  It is under the `Views/Home` directory and my `actionResult` statement is in the `HomeController.cs` file.

Comment: @Keven Have you added anything to the view?  When you add a new view to the solution it doesn't have anything in it usually, other than a heading.

Comment: @asymptoticFault Yes.  Just some simple html: `h1`, `div`, `p`, etc.

Comment: @Keven I guess I don't see what the problem is then.

Comment: @asymptoticFault Are you saying that I have all of the pieces of the puzzle and that something else is wrong?

Comment: @Keven It seems that way.  Try setting a break in your action method and see if it is being hit.  This will tell you if your routing is working.  Are you receiving any errors or simply just a blank page?

Comment: @asymptoticFault Just a blank page.  No errors. I suppose I could step through it...

Comment: Dumb question but are you actually inputting /Home/WebPage as the url in the browser?  Mvc usually sets your default url to Home/Index.  If that's not the case then if you want more help with this I would add some more information like your cshtml markup, route config and controller code.

Comment: @JustinMichaels The url is `http://localhost:[port]/Home/WebPage.cshtml`

Comment: well that's your issue.  Extensions urls are baked in to mvc.  That's navigate you to the file which should return a 404 (Not Found).  remove the .cshtml from the url.

Comment: @JustinMichaels Hah, wow.  Thanks Man.  That actually was the issue... kinda ridiculous how something so little has plagued me for so long...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment @Keven your trying to evaluate to the file but with Mvc your getting extensionless urls.  That isn't technically a simple html page.  It's a razor view that when data is applied to generates your output which is html.

I'm guessing your route.config looks something like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

This is saying that your expecting your urls to look like **http://localhost:[port]/[controller name]/[action name]** or in the case if you have a querystring parameter named id **http://localhost:[port]/[controller name]/[action name]/[id]**.  To bring this full circle your url for that page based on the route above would be **http://localhost:[port]/home/webpage**.

Here's the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX) on routing